# Appending Row to PHP generated table row using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Using Jquery I am supposed to get id generated by php foreach loop and create a new row with input text where each value will be filled up by jquery. In short it is like inline editing. The difference is that instead of inline, I append new row for inline editing. And please see what I have progressed so far and help me get it working.

The PHP Part mysale.php:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>receipt</th>
      <th>month</th>
    </tr><form action="" method="POST" id="saleEdi">
<?php
      foreach($sales as sale):
          echo '<tr>';
          echo "<td class='editSale'>{$sale['id']}</td>";//click here
          echo "<td class='sName'>{$sale['name']}</td>";
          echo "<td>{$sale['receipt']}</td>";
          echo "<td>{$sale['month']}</td>";
          echo '</tr>';
       endforeach;
?>
```

The Jquery Part

```
$(document).on("click",".editSale",function(){
var sale = $('.editSale').text();
var name = $('.editName').text(); 
var i=$('table tr').length;
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="saleid" value="'+$('.editSale').text(sale)+i+'"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="name" value="'+$('.editName').text(name)+i+'"></td>';
  //and so on
    $('table').append(html);
    i++;
});
```

The problem is that I could not get it working. I want to append new row with data in the input value below the php generated row whenever I click on each id or each row itself.

Comment: where is .editNam selector in code ?

Comment: also change Var to var  . Var sale to var sale. Var name to var name

Comment: Wouldn't be better to make the table editable than to append a new line to edit the values?

Comment: @William Janoti, But I want to create new row and use that new for inline editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your code like below  . [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/48d4wx9k/1/)

from your code i replace  `$('.editSale').text();` to `$(this).text();` . it will give clicked element text.

`$(this).next('td').text();` give text from next td value of clicked element

HTML

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>receipt</th>
  <th>month</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class='editSale'>1</td>
    <td class='sName'>name 1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>12</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class='editSale'>2</td>
    <td class='sName'>name 2</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

JQUERY

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on("click",".editSale",function(){
     var sale = $(this).text();
     var name = $(this).next('td').text(); 
     var html = '';
     html += '<td><input type="text" name="saleid" value="'+sale+'"></td>';
     html += '<td><input type="text" name="name" value="'+name+'"></td>';
     $('table').append(html);
  });
 });
```

UPDATE 2  .  append row after clicked element. also appended element when click on other element.   [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/48d4wx9k/3/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on("click",".editSale",function(){
    $('table').find('.appended').remove()
    var sale = $(this).text();
    var name = $(this).next('td').text(); 
    var html = '<tr class="appended">';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="saleid" value="'+sale+'"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="name" value="'+name+'"></td>';
    html += '<td>&nbsp:</td>';
    html += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $(this).parent('tr').after(html);
  });
 });
```

Comment: keep appending means?

Comment: Whenever I click, it appends, and it does not append just below the clicked row.

Comment: ok so you want to append it below clicked row rignt ? let me update code '

Comment: I will be very pleased. Also append only once, and remove the appended whenever we click other row.

Comment: Thank you very much...This is the expected output.